# Strange sap.m.TextArea behavior inside a sap.m.List

Tags: sapui5

I'm using sap.m.TextArea control inside sap.m.List where the values of each TextArea were mapped to a JSONModel. Here is the xml-view code:

```
<List id="otherPicList" growing="true" items="{ path : 'newRequest>/OtherPic' }" >
    <items>     
        <CustomListItem type="Inactive">
        <Image id="otherPic" src="{newRequest>pic}" width="90px" height="60px" />   
        <VBox>                  
            <TextArea value="{newRequest>text}"/>                                       
        </VBox> 
        </CustomListItem>
    </items>
</List>
```

When I start to type inside the sap.m.TextArea it freezes after the first character. I can only type one more character if I click outside the control and inside again. I think this bug happen because of the data binding inside a sap.m.List control.

If I set the value property without the model binding it works just fine. Is this a known bug or am I using wrong the control?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Data binding and growing list are not smart enough:

1. After the value of text area is changed and updated on the input event (after the key stroke), data binding is updated with the following diff:

   - 1 item is deleted
   - 2 item is updated
2. Growing List listens to data model change and does exactly the same: it deletes the changed item and creates it again.

When the text area inside of list item is deleted from DOM, focus is lost. The new text area does not get focus and any subsequent keystroke goes to nowhere.

I will report this issue to development.

Answer (score 0):

It is working for my code snippet. Please run and check. Maybe there is something else causing your issue.

```html
<script src="https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js" id="sap-ui-bootstrap" data-sap-ui-theme="sap_bluecrystal" data-sap-ui-libs="sap.m,sap.ui.commons"></script>
 
 
 <!-- define an XMLView - normally done in a separate file -->
 <script id="view1" type="sapui5/xmlview">
  <mvc:View xmlns:core="sap.ui.core" xmlns:layout="sap.ui.commons.layout" xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc" xmlns="sap.m"
    controllerName="my.own.controller" xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
   <List id="otherPicList" items="{/test}" >
              <items>     
                  <CustomListItem type="Inactive">
                  <Image id="otherPic" src="{pic}" width="90px" height="60px" />  
                  <VBox>                  
                      <TextArea value="{text}"/>                                       
                  </VBox> 
                  </CustomListItem>
              </items>
            </List>
  </mvc:View> 
 </script>
 
 
 <script>
  sap.ui.controller("my.own.controller", {
           
   onInit:function() {
              var data = {test:[{text:"123",pic:"https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/e25560c87abbbb90143653d98c9924dc?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG"},{text:"456",pic:"https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/e25560c87abbbb90143653d98c9924dc?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG"},{text:"789",pic:"https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/e25560c87abbbb90143653d98c9924dc?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG"},{text:"101112",pic:"https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/e25560c87abbbb90143653d98c9924dc?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG"}]};
              var oModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
              
              oModel.setData(data);
              this.getView().setModel(oModel);
            }
          
           
  });
  
  var myView = sap.ui.xmlview("myView", {viewContent:jQuery('#view1').html()}); // 
  myView.placeAt('content');
  
  
 </script>
 

 <body class='sapUiBody'>
  <div id='content'></div>
 </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out the problem, check out your code snippet including the property growing="true" inside the sap.m.List control. This property cause the strange behavior I was talking about.

```html
<script src="https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js" id="sap-ui-bootstrap" data-sap-ui-theme="sap_bluecrystal" data-sap-ui-libs="sap.m,sap.ui.commons"></script>
 
 
 <!-- define an XMLView - normally done in a separate file -->
 <script id="view1" type="sapui5/xmlview">
  <mvc:View xmlns:core="sap.ui.core" xmlns:layout="sap.ui.commons.layout" xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc" xmlns="sap.m"
    controllerName="my.own.controller" xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
   <List id="otherPicList" growing="true" items="{/test}" >
              <items>     
                  <CustomListItem type="Inactive">
                  <Image id="otherPic" src="{pic}" width="90px" height="60px" />  
                  <VBox>                  
                      <TextArea value="{text}"/>                                       
                  </VBox> 
                  </CustomListItem>
              </items>
            </List>
  </mvc:View> 
 </script>
 
 
 <script>
  sap.ui.controller("my.own.controller", {
           
   onInit:function() {
              var data = {test:[{text:"123",pic:"https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/e25560c87abbbb90143653d98c9924dc?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG"},{text:"456",pic:"https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/e25560c87abbbb90143653d98c9924dc?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG"},{text:"789",pic:"https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/e25560c87abbbb90143653d98c9924dc?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG"},{text:"101112",pic:"https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/e25560c87abbbb90143653d98c9924dc?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG"}]};
              var oModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
              
              oModel.setData(data);
              this.getView().setModel(oModel);
            }
          
           
  });
  
  var myView = sap.ui.xmlview("myView", {viewContent:jQuery('#view1').html()}); // 
  myView.placeAt('content');
  
  
 </script>
 

 <body class='sapUiBody'>
  <div id='content'></div>
 </body>
```